# how to associate floating ip address to a instance in openstack using terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-openstack

I am using terraform to create couple of instances in openstack and I would like to automatically assign floatings ip address to them without any manual intervention.

My .tf file is as below:

```
resource "openstack_networking_floatingip_v2" "floating-ip" {
 count  = 4
 pool = "floating-ip-pool" 
}

resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "fip-associate" {
floating_ip = openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.floating-ip.address[count.0]
instance_id = openstack_compute_instance_v2.terraform-vm.id[count.0]
}`
```

I am getting an error

> "Error: Missing resource instance key
>
> on image-provisioning.tf line 33, in resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "fip-associate":
>     33:   instance_id = openstack_compute_instance_v2.terraform-vm.id[count.0]"

My terraform version is : Terraform v0.12.24
+ provider.openstack 1.26.0

Answer (score 0):

able to resolve using for_each option in terraform :

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "terraform_vm" {

  image_id        = "f8b9189d-2518-4a32-b1ba-2046ea8d47fd"
  for_each        =  var.instance_name
  name            =  each.key
  flavor_id       = "3"
  key_pair        = "openstack vm key"
  security_groups = ["default"]

 network {
  name = "webapps-network"
 }
 }

resource "openstack_networking_floatingip_v2" "floating_ip" {
pool = "floating-ip-pool"
for_each        =  var.instance_name
```

}

```
resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "fip_associate" {
for_each        =  var.instance_name
floating_ip = openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.floating_ip[each.key].address
instance_id = openstack_compute_instance_v2.terraform_vm[each.key].id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `port_id` in the associate. That can be looked up using the compute instance IPv4 address:

```
resource "openstack_networking_floatingip_v2" "floating-ip" {
  # count = 4
  pool  = "floating-ip-pool" 
}

data "openstack_networking_port_v2" "terraform-vm" {
  fixed_ip = openstack_compute_instance_v2.terraform-vm.access_ip_v4
}

resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "fip-associate" {
  floating_ip = openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.floating-ip.address
  port_id     = data.openstack_networking_port_v2.terraform-vm.id
}
```